# alternating, conditional rolling count in pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

In a Technical Trading book by Larry Connors, I came across a simple indicator that for a financial asset time-series, it measures the number of consecutive closes in the same direction. Individual days are given a score of -1, 0, or +1 depending whether the close is lower, equal or higher than the previous close.

The series increments each day the close is in the same direction, and when the direction changes, it resets to -1, 0, or 1.

This is what I have thus far:

```
df['sign'] = np.sign(np.log(df['close']/df['close'].shift(1)).map(str)
df['streak'] = df.groupby((df['sign'] != df['sign'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
```

This capture the streak, but does not indicate the direction, and because I use the asset's return

> (np.log(df['close']/df['close'].shift(1))

I am not capturing the condition of 0 when close today = close yesterday. 
How can I modify the code to capture the effect; and without the "sign" column if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 99% of the way there:

```
df['sign'] = np.sign(np.log(df['close']/df['close'].shift(1))).map(str)
df['streak'] = df.groupby((df['sign'] !=df['sign'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
df['final_streak'] = df['sign'].astype(float)*df['streak']
```

Should give you what you want (not sure how to do it without using the sign column, this solution seemed simplest given the work you have already done).